# Getting 500 internal server error when trying to add data into mysql database using ajax

Tags: javascript, java, mysql, ajax, netbeans

I'm making a simple login page and for that i'm using html ajax,javascript,java servlets and mysql.But when i'm trying to add the data of the user into the database by clicking submit button i'm getting 500 internal server error.
Here is my code.
   this is the code using ajax and javascript to pass the data to the servlet.

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    var get1=new XMLHttpRequest();
     function login()
     {
       console.log("Signup");
       var username=document.getElementById("username").value;
       var pword=document.getElementById("pword").value;
       var confpwd=document.getElementById("confpwd").value;
       var email=document.getElementById("email").value;
       var fname=document.getElementById("fname").value;
       var lname=document.getElementById("lname").value;
       var gender=document.getElementById("gender").value;
       var data=username+" "+pword+" "+confpwd+" "+email+" "+fname+" "+lname+" "+gender;
       console.log("here"+" "+data);
       get1.open("get","/loginpage/NewServlet?id1="+ data,true);
       get1.onreadystatechange=process;
       get1.send(null);
     }

     function process()
     {
        var JSONtopicobject=eval( "("+get1.responseText + ")" );
        console.log("Signup successful");
     }
```

And here is my java servlet code for adding data into the database

```
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
 {

     PrintWriter uout=response.getWriter();
     String textp=request.getParameter("data");
     String[] t=textp.split(" ");
     try{
        //get a connection


      con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/login","root","ATul1996@@");

      //create a statement
      Statement st=con.createStatement();
      //Execute a query
      String exec="INSERT INTO login "+" (username,pwd,email,fname,lname,gender)" + " VALUES('as','op','py','po','lp','ll')";
      st.executeUpdate(exec);
      uout.println("insertion done");
      g="insert complete";
      }catch(SQLException e)
       {
        System.out.println(e);
       }
      finally{

       try {
           con.close();
           } catch (SQLException ex) {
           Logger.getLogger(NewServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
           }
     }
      response.setContentType("text/html");
      response.getWriter().write(g);
      response.getWriter().flush();
      response.getWriter().close();
}
```

Comment: can you expose the exception ?

Comment: I mean, you get a `500` back on the client, but what's going on on the other side?

Comment: The input given by the client is added into the database when he clicks on signup button.The servlet code is to add the user's input into the database  that i have created on mysql workbench

Comment: I'm new to this, i mean this is the first time i have created a database for my web application and i'm using mysql workbench for it.The database is working completely fine when i'm using it as it is i.e. with no html or anything.But when i'm using the same code here i'm getting 500 internal server error

Comment: The issue is going to be somewhere on the java side. Try inserting even more try/catch statements so you can identify which part is failing, since this is probably a web server error.  PS: Use `JSON.parse()` instead of `eval()` to transform the response text into an object. PPS: Which web server are you running?

Comment: @Shilly glassfish server.JSON.parse() did not help.

Comment: Also,i checked that it is not being able to establish a connection with the server